# Encoding to utf-8 binary data in Flask-Jinja2 while for-looping

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am using for loop in jinja2 template to extract data from database.

`{{p.author.profile_picture}}` in my database is saved as binary data. I have to encode it in utf-8 format to see the image on the website. Can I change it somehow during loop? Or is there any easy way to pass it back to my python backend? I am using Flask.

```py
    {% for p in posts %}
    <div>
      <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{p.author.profile_picture}}">
      <h3>{{ p.author.username }}</h3>
      <h2>{{ p.title }}</h2>
      {{ p.text | safe }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date.desc())
        return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
```

Comment: There's no `UTF-8 binary data`. UTF8 is a way of encoding *text* into bytes. Python 3 strings are UTF8. What you need to do is the opposite, encode bytes into a string

Answer (score 2):

You should [base64-encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) the JPEG compressed binary image data to include it in the data URL.
If you want to do this in a jinja2 template, I recommend that you use a [custom filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#custom-filters).

Create the function and add it to the jinja environment under filters.

```
import base64

def b64encode(data):
    return base64.b64encode(data).decode()

app.jinja_env.filters['b64encode'] = b64encode
```

You can use the filter in your template in this way.

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ p.author.profile_picture | b64encode }}" />
```

You should now see the image.

Comment: Thank you!!! This is exactly what I needed. It works. :)